# how to change the server name in the connection manager through variables

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, ssis-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have a requirement in which I have to dynamically changed the server name in the connection manager through variables. I am going to pass the server name through variable from the stored procedure. Reason to do that is because Package will initially be created in Dev enviornment but later will be deployed on UAT and then on Live. as a developer, i dont have access to UAT and Live. The person who is going to deploy the package will have no knowledge of ssis. I

anyone got any idea as how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your Connection Manager, and in the Properties click the ellipsis by Expressions.  Select the `ServerName` property and assign the necessary variable or parameter to it.  It may also be helpful to set `DelayValidation` to true on any Data Flow Tasks and `ValidateExternalMetadata` to false on source/destination components, as long as you've confirmed the metadata will correctly align at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done with some type of configuration.

Up until ssis 2012 this was only done with a config file, but since 2012 parameters are also an option.

Config File:

Set up your initial config file in DEV and set the property of your connection string in your connection manager to be configured by the config file. You will need to alter the config file as you promote your package through your environments.

When providing instructions for promotion have the agent apply the config file that you established.

Parameters:

Very similar but much more direct from Agent. Parameters need to be set up on "package or project" and then an expression made referencing the parameter on the property being configured (in your case a connection string to DB). You can set the parameter directly in Agent when establishing a job.

As a side note:

You typically also need to define a filepath through config as you promote through the environments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at package configurations? Use an execute SQL Task to fetch the value into variable, and on the connection manager, right click and select properties. On the drop down select the ServerName property and use your variable here to dynamically set it to what is on your config table/file. Dont forget to set the connection to DelayValidation = True to overcome runtime compilation errors.